# Destroy window not closing all windows properly

Tags: python, tkinter

I have two queries in this section.

1. In my code i have created two frames under root, the first frame have "NEXT" button to go on second frame. In second frame there is Run button, which has mapped with close_window function. It should close all windows properly. But in my case not closing it.
2. When i click "Run" i need to close all windows and need to execute another script on the same directory. Is that possible to do it ?

```
from Tkinter import *


def close_window():
    frame2.destroy()
    frame1.destroy()


def swap_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()


root = Tk()
root.geometry("900x650+220+20")
root.title("Testing")
root.configure(borderwidth="1", relief="sunken", cursor="arrow", background="#dbd8d7", highlightcolor="black")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

frame2 = Frame(root, width=900, height=650)
frame1 = Frame(root, width=900, height=650)

Button1 = Button(frame1, text="Next", width=10, height=2, bg="#dbd8d7", command=lambda: swap_frame(frame2))
Button1.place(x=580, y=580)

Button2 = Button(frame2, text="Run", width=10, height=2, bg="#dbd8d7", command=close_window,)
Button2.place(x=580, y=580)


frame2.grid(row=0, column=0)
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

what is wrong in the code?

Comment: If you want the entire window closed, why are you closing only the two frames?

Comment: How i can close all window. I thought this is the way to close all window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"Destroy window not closing all windows properly"*

Nor should it. `destroy` method destroys a widget, and when a widget is destroyed so are its children.

Since neither `frame1` nor `frame2` are *'windows'* or a window's parents, there's no window destruction taking place.

---

> *"When I click `"Run"` I need to close all windows and need to execute another script in the same directory. Is that possible to do it?"*

It is possible. Use `quit` on any GUI object, instead of `destroy`. It stops the `mainloop`, hence destroying the entire GUI. In that it solves the first problem as well. Then import `another_script`:

```
...
def close_window():
    frame1.quit()
...
root.mainloop()
import another_script
```